# How to deploy local python script on AWS lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. I have to deploy my python script on AWS. My project flow is like this

```
S3
SNS
Lambda Function
My Python script
```

Whenever our client put any file on s3 then SNS notify the Lambda function and lambda function trigger my script and pass the s3 key and bucket name to my script.

Please help me on how to configure this.

Comment: This is way too broad. Start with the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-create-function.html) and ask any more specific questions you have as you go through the docs.

Comment: Which part do you want help in configuring?

Comment: First of all you can directly invoke lambda from s3 (no use of sns) and full implementation you can find here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write your script with a function `lambda_handler` as a main caller function,So your code should start with `lambda_handler`. And directly copy paste your code in the aws lambda. And that's it.

eg.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        /// Your code goes here
        return 'Completed'
    except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt) as e:
        return 'Error occurred'
```

And if you want to run it with some third party package eg. `requests`.
Then install these packages in a directory and create a plain zip along with your script without any nesting. 
Read here for [more](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)
OR You can take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzlxWBs1Qt4)

About configuring the AWS lambda - Read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html), it provides all the details about each option. Select the configuration options that fits your requirement